MPI linking issues, -Wl,-t shows library listed and nm -D -C lists symbol
I understand that linking issues can be hard to resolve as they are very dependent on the exact setup of the system, but my usual trick of tracing the output has failed. I'm looking for more things to check/help debug the issue to add to my bag of tricks.
I am trying to compile Pastix4Calculix, and there is a big makefile generated with cmake. When I run it with the right options, I get the following error (I know this is in and of itself not helpful)
/usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o): in function MPI::Op::Init(void (*)(void const*, void*, int, MPI::Datatype const&), bool)': cpp_sort.cpp:(.text._ZN3MPI2Op4InitEPFvPKvPviRKNS_8DatatypeEEb[_ZN3MPI2Op4InitEPFvPKvPviRKNS_8DatatypeEEb]+0x1d): undefined reference to ompi_mpi_cxx_op_intercept' /usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o): in function MPI::Intracomm::Clone() const': cpp_sort.cpp:(.text._ZNK3MPI9Intracomm5CloneEv[_ZNK3MPI9Intracomm5CloneEv]+0x40): undefined reference to MPI::Comm::Comm()' /usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o): in function MPI::Graphcomm::Clone() const': cpp_sort.cpp:(.text._ZNK3MPI9Graphcomm5CloneEv[_ZNK3MPI9Graphcomm5CloneEv]+0x3b): undefined reference to MPI::Comm::Comm()' /usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o): in function MPI::Cartcomm::Sub(bool const*) const': cpp_sort.cpp:(.text._ZNK3MPI8Cartcomm3SubEPKb[_ZNK3MPI8Cartcomm3SubEPKb]+0xa1): undefined reference to MPI::Comm::Comm()' /usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o): in function MPI::Intracomm::Create_graph(int, int const*, int const*, bool) const': cpp_sort.cpp:(.text._ZNK3MPI9Intracomm12Create_graphEiPKiS2_b[_ZNK3MPI9Intracomm12Create_graphEiPKiS2_b]+0x42): undefined reference to MPI::Comm::Comm()' /usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o): in function MPI::Cartcomm::Clone() const': cpp_sort.cpp:(.text._ZNK3MPI8Cartcomm5CloneEv[_ZNK3MPI8Cartcomm5CloneEv]+0x3b): undefined reference to MPI::Comm::Comm()' /usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o):cpp_sort.cpp:(.text._ZNK3MPI9Intracomm11Create_cartEiPKiPKbb[_ZNK3MPI9Intracomm11Create_cartEiPKiPKbb]+0xaa): more undefined references to MPI::Comm::Comm()' follow /usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3MPI8DatatypeE[_ZTVN3MPI8DatatypeE]+0x78): undefined reference to MPI::Datatype::Free()' /usr/bin/ld: ../libpastix.a(cpp_sort.cpp.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3MPI3WinE[_ZTVN3MPI3WinE]+0x48): undefined reference to MPI::Win::Free()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The first thing I try when I get linking errors is to trace the output, and so I ran:
/usr/bin/g++ ... -Q -v -Wl,-t | grep mpi_cxx (where the ... represents what was ran in the makefile, gotten via the verbose option)
and in the output there is indeed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so
So then I wanted to check that the symbol was actually there, so I ran nm -D -C /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so | grep ompi_mpi_cxx_op_intercept
and indeed the result shows that it is available: 00000000000153f0 T ompi_mpi_cxx_op_intercept
Even if I remove the demangling: nm -D /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so | grep ompi_mpi_cxx_op_intercept, I still get the same result.
what am I missing?
